# AJAX and -1 response

Tags: ajax

I know this has come up a number of times but it is driving me nuts. I've spend hours trying to debug it.

My AJAX isn't working for non-logged in users.

Here's me action:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ah_update', array($tracker, 'update_tracking'), "1");
add_action('wp_ajax_ah_update', array($tracker, 'update_tracking'), "1");
```

I've placed them inbetween is_admin and out of it. I've taken the server side code out of the class and put it in its own function. But nothing works.

I should state that it works fine for all logged-in users

I've done a var_dump() on $_GET['request'] and it all looked fine.

```
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );

die('-1');
```

If I change the admin-ajax.php code to this it works fine:

```
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {

    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );

} else {

    die('-1');

}
```

I'm a total loss as to what is causing this to happen.

Perhaps there is something else in the script that is blocking no-logged in user access, but I can't see it.

Comment: Just a guess: Did you change the line endings? Maybe during the transfer of this file to the server?

Comment: Does your actual AJAX callback end with a call to `die()`?  If your code doesn't, then WordPress will fire the action hook as expected and still call `die('-1')` afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should end all "async" functions with die() or exit, otherwise WordPress does it for you returning -1.

Comment: At the bottom of the callback I had return *database query". So I removed the return from the beginning of the database query and put die() at the end and it works fine now. Thanks for all your responses.